# Disable in EsLint "react / jsx-props-no-spreading" error in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, eslint

After installing EsLint one of the errors that appears to me is the following:

> Prop spreading is forbiddeneslint(react/jsx-props-no-spreading)

I want to create a rule in the EsLint configuration to ignore this error but the examples I found do not work.

This is the format to create a global exception:

```
...
"react/jsx-props-no-spreading": [{
    "html": "ignore" / "enforce",
    "custom": "ignore" / "enforce",
    "exceptions": [<string>]
}]
...
```

And this is the format to create an exception in a specific file:

```
{
  "rules": {...},
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*-test.js","*.spec.js"],
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-expressions": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here, the code that I currently have:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: "../../.eslintrc.js",
  rules: {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error",  {"devDependencies": true}]
  },
  env: {
    "jest": true
  }
};
```

At the moment, I just keep giving the same error continuously.

Thank you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try turning off the `"react/jsx-props-no-spreading"` rule:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: "../../.eslintrc.js",
  rules: {
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error",  {"devDependencies": true}],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
  },
  env: {
    "jest": true
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, just dialing "off" is deactivated, thank you very much for your advice

Comment: Since this answer received a lot of attention than what I expected, Please NOTE that props spreading is an [anti pattern](https://codeburst.io/react-anti-pattern-jsx-spread-attributes-59d1dd53677f) and is highly discouraged

Comment: I don't get why it's more of an anti pattern than spreading into any other object would be and the linked article has a stupid example. Are there any better explanations?

Answer (score 5):

As an example if there is not so much errors you can ignore them by
    `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Or you can write for concrete error like

```
// eslint-disable jsx-props-no-spreading
```

Comment: Is this line valid for the whole file or is it turning off the check only for the following line?

Comment: @FMaz008, sorry for late response. eslint-disable valid for whole file depend on line which is starts(f.e. from 5 line till the end). In case of eslint-disable-next-line it's only has effect on 1 line