# How to resolve eslint error: "prop spreading is forbidden" in a custom route component?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-router-dom

How can I resolve the eslint error: "prop spreading is forbidden" in a custom route component?

This error occurs on lines 3 and 6 below:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (
        localStorage.getItem('user') ?
          <Component {...props} /> :
          <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />
  )}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ES lint discourages the use of prop spreading so that no unwanted/unintended props are being passed to the component.
More details here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md

To disable it for the particular file, you can put: `/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */` at the top line in your component file.
For disabling it for all files, try this: [Disable in EsLint "react / jsx-props-no-spreading" error in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167467/disable-in-eslint-react-jsx-props-no-spreading-error-in-reactjs)

Edited comments as per answer below

Comment: thank u! i added a rule "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["error", {"custom": "ignore"}] and it solved the problem

Answer (score 29):

For ESLint is important which type of comment do you use, the legit one is:

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
```

Comment: This ... after banging my head against the wall for way too long. Comment type does matter apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode and have eslint plugin installed then simply `hover over the error it will open the dialog as shown in image -> quick fix -> disable for this line.`

Doing this will add proper lint comment automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one just to comment out the below line:-

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same ESLint error when I used `react-hook-form`. I resolved it by adding the following code into `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["error", {
    "html": "enforce",
    "custom": "enforce",
    "explicitSpread": "enforce",
    "exceptions": ["input", "textarea"]
  }],
  ...
}
```

Code with the problem from a React component:

```
const InputElement =
    type === TEXTAREA_TYPE ? (
      <textarea className="textarea" id={id} {...register(id, { required })} />
    ) : (
      <input className="input" type={type} id={id} {...register(id, { required })} />
    );
```