# Missing "key" prop for element in iterator and Prop spreading is forbidden

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I got those 2 errors in my code, how can I fix those without using "suppress eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading/ or eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key" for this line?

```
 <UitkTableHead>
              {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                <UitkTableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}> //  Prop spreading is forbidden 
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <UitkTableCell scope="col" {...column.getHeaderProps()}> //Missing "key" prop for element in iterator 
                      {column.render('Header')}
                    </UitkTableCell>
                  ))}
                </UitkTableRow>
              ))}
```

I expect to make the code stop showing those errors, how to change the code to make that happened instead of add the ignore comment.

Edit:
Here is my rules

```
 "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": [
          "error",
          {
            "ts-ignore": "allow-with-description"
          }
        ],
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "class-methods-use-this": "off",
        "no-shadow": "off",
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error", {"variables": false}],
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react/require-default-props": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "global-require": "off",
        "import/no-dynamic-require": "off",
        "camelcase": "off",
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
        "no-empty-function": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method": "off"
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing "key" prop for element in iterator

This error comes from using the `.map()` method on an array in React. When you use `.map()`, React wants a way to easily differentiate each item it is mapping when it compares the DOMs. To fix this, all you need to do is add a `key` with a unique identifier to each item, and if you don't have a unique identifier, you can add a parameter to `.map()` to grab the index of the item it is currently using:

```
{headerGroup.headers.map((column, index) => (
    <UitkTableCell key={index} scope="col" {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
        {column.render('Header')}
    </UitkTableCell>
))}
```

Important note, this way of using the index should ONLY be used if you cannot supply a unique key yourself, either through a library that generates one or by giving each object a `key` property themselves.

> Prop spreading is forbidden

The easiest way to fix that would be to tell ESLint not to consider this file when parsing for that error, but there are different ways:

1. Disable the ESLint prop spreading error for the specific file by putting this comment at Line 1 in the component file: `/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading *`
2. Disabling the following line for the ESLint prop spreading error in the project's ESLint config: `react/jsx-props-no-spreading`
3. Do not use spreading. Destructure the spread argument before you render the element, pass that instead, and then `return` the mapped arguments that you want rendered:

```
{headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
    const hgProps = headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps();
    return (
        <UitkTableRow {hgProps}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column, index) => (
                <UitkTableCell key={index} scope="col" {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render('Header')}
                </UitkTableCell>
            ))}
        </UitkTableRow>
    )
))}
```

If it happens below at the props for `uitkTableCell` as well, you can follow the same rule. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @erikohara99, I add this line in json file but still got the spreading error, any idea why it happened?
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",

Comment: As long as it's in package.json or an eslintrc file as follows: "eslintConfig": { "rules" : { "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off" } } it should work fine. Did you make sure to restart your dev server after you added it?

Answer (score 0):

for Prop spreading is forbidden error refer:

[How to resolve eslint error: "prop spreading is forbidden" in a custom route component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726028/how-to-resolve-eslint-error-prop-spreading-is-forbidden-in-a-custom-route-com)

for missing key error:
you need to mention a unique value from map returned items in UitkTableCell as <UitkTableCell scope="col" key={column.unique_id}